# How to check if user is authenticated by cookie session on Laravel?

Tags: php, session, laravel, authentication, cookies

Well, at the moment I have 2 sites.

- One with laravel (Database Session driver).
- Another with regular php.

The two sites are in the same domain, so we can share cookies. But I need a simple way to check if the cookie session is really authenticated on the laravel site.

My idea is expose a method over the laravel site to call it from the other php project, something like this:

```
public function checkUser($cookie)
{
    return Auth::check($cookie);
}
```

There is a simple method like Auth::check($cookie) ? or what I need to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Comment: can you share your final code please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Auth::user()` will return a logged in user or `FALSE`.

Comment: Auth:user($cookie) ? are you sure this is correct? I will call this method from external site, so the other site doesn't know which user is, it just have the cookie.

Comment: If you send the Cookie through a http-header, the Auth::user() alone should work.